# Numbered lists get erroneous numbers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Look at my answer here: [Printing multiple files from Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/319982/1)

You'll see I have an ordered list 1-8. After the 6th item, I have a pre/code section and after that points 7 and 8. However, 7 and 8 is listed as 1 and 2. If you edit the answer, you'll see that it says 7 and 8.

Bug.

Answer (score 8):

[Fixed it](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/319982/2) for you. And no, this is *not* a bug, but how Markdown works.

The key thing is to indent one level further *and* use a 4-space indent, so make it 8 spaces to indent. See also the [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> To put a code block within a list item, the code block needs to be indented twice — 8 spaces or two tabs:
>
> ```
>     *   A list item with a code block:
>
>             <code goes here>
> ```

More tips:

- No need to use incrementing numbers. Use `1.` for every list item.
- Also no need for `<code>` or `<pre>` blocks - we don't have that in Markdown as far as I know.

So, an example:

---

```
1. item text.

   some text below the item but under the same item.

1. next item increments numbers automatically.

1. Here's some code:

        Code block line 1
        Code block line 2

1. And here's item 4.
```

---

Renders to

---

1. item text.

   some text below the item but under the same item.
2. next item increments numbers automatically.
3. Here's some code:

   ```
   Code block line 1
   Code block line 2
   ```
4. And here's item 4.

Comment: The key here, if you don't want to break your list, indent everything that needs to be under that list.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `<pre>` tag.

It IS allowed and works great as well, because **as long as you indent your text** it won't break the **sequence** in your ordered lists.

You can check all the allowed tags in the following link:

- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/228133)

Comment: Well, I see your point, but it *did* break the sequence for the OP because these weren't indented.

Comment: Tank you, I edited my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: Using correct [markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) is best.  If what is being added is external (code/text/example/table/ascii) and not part of the question/answer itself, then consider using <pre> tag.